# iTextSharp duplicate fields but change field names

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a task to merge several PDFs into a single one. I'm using iTextSharp. The issue I'm having is the merging involves the same 1 page form filled out X numbers of times with different information. Once the PDFs are merged into one, the fields on all X of those pages have the same name, so any change to one alters all the others.

Is there a way I can alter the fields programatically as I go so they are truly distinct fields in the final PDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the fields before adding the pages with:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.renameField("personal.loginname", "personal.login");
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I had trouble with this. I think it could have been made to work, if I changed the names first and then filled the fields using the new names.

I found it easier to use Sola Oderinde's answer from this question, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343657/is-it-possible-to-modify-pdf-form-field-names